# Black screen on Dell Inspiron

Tags: windows, memory, dell-inspiron

I have a Dell Inspiron 1440 laptop. I had a problem twice yesterday that while operating my laptop got a black screen accompanied by a high beeping sound. The first time this problem occurred, I ran the diagnostic and found the following error code:

```
Error code-0147
Msg error code: 2000-0147
Msg -optical drive 0-selftest failed.
```

But after running the diagnostic everything was OK.
The second time the problem occurred during restarting after the Dell logo screen disappeared, a black screen appeared with the following message:

```
The amount of memory has changed.
  If you did not change the memory...
  To resolve this issue ,try to reset the memory.

Press f1 To continue,f2 to Run the setup utility.
Press f5 to run onboard diagnostic.
```

Why is this problem occurring, and what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

> The amount of memory has changed. If you did not change the memory... To resolve this issue ,try to reset the memory.
>
> Press f1 To continue,f2 to Run the setup utility. Press f5 to run onboard diagnostic.

This is your system reporting that the amount of RAM in your system has changed.

> Error code-0147 Msg error code: 2000-0147 Msg -optical drive 0-selftest failed.

"optical drive 0" is most likely your CD-Drive. However, considering your RAM issue, it is more than likely *just* your RAM. RAM failing can cause so many odd errors. If it were me, I'd try replacing your RAM first with known good RAM. If that doesn't help, your motherboard could also be suspect. I say that because you got both these errors at once with no other connection.

As a closing thought, you didn't say what you were doing when your computer initially failed. If you were gaming, was it possible that your laptop overheated?

Comment: I was playing VLC media player at the time of failure.

Comment: I'd still venture to say that it is most likely your RAM. Run a thorough memtest with one stick of RAM in at a time (to isolate which is bad, if any) http://www.memtest86.com/